# Svg transparent mask displays weird vertical lines

Tags: svg, mask

**Goal**
My goal is to have a full screen loading animation with a transparent svg mask and a video playing behind.

**Issue**
Vertical lines appears on the left and the right of the svg as you can see here (in circles):
[image]

```html
      <svg id="DÉPRESSION" viewBox="0 0 637 110">
          <mask id="mask_title" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M100.12,258h28.19c21,0,37.74,17.42,37.74,38.84s-16.21,38.85-37.74,38.85H100.12Zm26.75,62.37c12.76,0,22-10.54,22-23.53s-9.21-23.53-22-23.53H116.76v47.06Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M176.15,258H224.1v16.2H192.8v13.54h30.3v15.76H192.8V319.4h31.85v16.31h-48.5Zm26-20.87h15.54l-16,15.32H191.47Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M265.61,311.74H253.85v24H237.2V258h28.41a26.86,26.86,0,0,1,0,53.72ZM264,273.33h-10.1v23H264c6.21,0,11.1-4.88,11.1-11.54A11.22,11.22,0,0,0,264,273.33Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M349.08,307.19c8.88,6.66,10.77,14.43,10.77,22.53v6H343.2v-6c0-8.22-5.55-15-14-15H319v21H302.35V258H331.1a28.73,28.73,0,0,1,28.75,28.63C359.85,297.09,354.74,302.75,349.08,307.19Zm-20-33.86H319v26.53h10.1a13.27,13.27,0,1,0,0-26.53Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M372,258H419.9v16.2H388.6v13.54h30.3v15.76H388.6V319.4h31.86v16.31H372Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M463.08,288.54a23.37,23.37,0,0,1,23.31,23.31c0,12.87-10.44,23.86-23.31,23.86H432.33V319.4h29c4.33,0,7.88-3.11,7.88-7.44s-3.55-7.44-7.88-7.44h-10c-12.76,0-22.86-10.87-22.86-23.53a22.92,22.92,0,0,1,22.86-23h25.86v15.87H452.54a7.33,7.33,0,1,0,0,14.65Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M526.46,288.54a23.37,23.37,0,0,1,23.31,23.31c0,12.87-10.43,23.86-23.31,23.86H495.72V319.4h29c4.33,0,7.89-3.11,7.89-7.44s-3.56-7.44-7.89-7.44h-10c-12.77,0-22.87-10.87-22.87-23.53a22.92,22.92,0,0,1,22.87-23h25.86v15.87H515.92a7.33,7.33,0,1,0,0,14.65Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M559.76,258h16.65v77.69H559.76Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M626.25,337.26c-22.64,0-39.74-17.42-39.74-40.28s17.1-40.29,39.74-40.29S666,274.11,666,297,648.89,337.26,626.25,337.26Zm0-16.31c12.87,0,22.31-10.21,22.31-24s-9.44-24-22.31-24-22.31,10.21-22.31,24S613.37,321,626.25,321Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
              <path class="cls-1" d="M675.65,258h14.2l32.08,35.4V258h16v79.13l-46.28-52.5v51.06h-16Z" transform="translate(-100.12 -237.15)"/>
          </mask>
          <rect fill="#FFFFFF" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      </svg>
```

I have made a codepen so you can see by yourself : https://codepen.io/Accolade/pen/WNjveQr
In this case, I have replaced video by a background animation.

**EDIT : codePen link has been modified**

**EDIT 2 :**
The current solution I have found is to add a really small scale to the svg tag so it hides the glitch

```
svg{
  transform: scale(1.0001);
}
```

Comment: Seems your code sample lacks some style or properties (fill="white" in mask presumably) and has extra rect in mask that should not be there, and mask is not addressed in the second rect. And you are apparently linking some unrelated CodePen.

Comment: Fill properties are set in CSS in my example. Sorry but both rect are necessary to make it work. The codepen is the right one by the way.

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to see in the codepen. You'll need to fix the example in the question so that it actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson Hard to guess what OP really fights with (and in what device), but FWIW, here's a pen that produces quite similar glitches like depicted in the question (in Firefox; in Chrome it is glitching way more): https://codepen.io/myf/pen/VwbYRWj?editors=1100 It was necessary to add two otherwise superfluous details there (lines with comments) to get the glitch exhibit reliably.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong codePen link, I have changed it with normally the good one...

Comment: The edges of your text outlines are hard up against the edge of the mask. Try enlarging the mask so that there is a margin around the text. I suspect that things will look a lot better.

Comment: I tried to change width in mask and/or rect but nothing better. I agree that my path is too close from the edges but I didn't manage to get free space against edges.

Comment: It looks like if a add a small transform scale to the svg so it hides that glitch. I edited my post.